# Scraping files from google drive - automated queries prevented by

Tags: python, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-drive-api

I wanted to scrape a few pdfs from a great history crash course I used to read a long time ago. Sadly, the old website is down and I only managed to get the old html code from archive.org
(the links I got work fine, ex: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRJiIvdbSoKcHpGUWJBUDZ2WDA/edit?usp=sharing).

This script is resulting in html files being downloaded, saying

,,We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.”

Is there a way to bypass this? I tried putting a few random delays into the code so this might be insufficient or i might be on google's blacklist for now.
(the text.txt file can be found here https://filebin.net/k2qw09embamx05ey )

```
import requests
import time
import random
def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,2))


    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)


f = open('text.txt')
long_string = f.readlines()
interesting_strings = []
for item in long_string:
    if 'drive.google' in item:
        interesting_strings.append(item)
print(interesting_strings)

interesting_strings = interesting_strings[0]
interesting_strings = interesting_strings.split('https://web.archive.org/web/20161219093036/')
links = []
for item in interesting_strings:
    if 'drive.google' in item:
        idx = item.find('"')
        links.append(item[:idx])
cntr = 1
for link in links:
    print(link)
    fname = './data/History_' + str(cntr)
    file_id = link.split('/')[-2]
    print('id:', file_id)
    destination = fname
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
    print('Getting file #', str(cntr))
    cntr += 1

    time.sleep(random.randrange(3,15) + random.random())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gdown`](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/):

```
import gdown

file_id = '0BzRJiIvdbSoKcHpGUWJBUDZ2WDA'
filename = 'file.pdf'

url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + file_id
gdown.download(url, filename, quiet=False)
```